# Как правильно обработать KeyEvent для клавиши Esc

Tags: java, клавиатура, esc

Читаем *.properties-файлы. Чтение только один раз.
После чтения файла, работать с ним через консоль, пока не нажата клавиша ESC.

Знаю что слегка топорно написано, но пока все что могу...

Пример кода main класса:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean bError = true;
    Mykey a = new Mykey();
    boolean enabled = a.keyPressed(); //каким образом тут надо взаимодействие определить

    Properties prop;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter name file: ");
        Scanner config = new Scanner(System.in);

        String c = config.nextLine();

        final String PATH_TO_PROPERTIES = "src/" + c + ".properties";

        FileInputStream fileInputStream;

        prop = new Properties();

        try {

            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(PATH_TO_PROPERTIES);
            bError = false;
            prop.load(fileInputStream);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Ошибка в программе: файл " + PATH_TO_PROPERTIES + " не обнаружено");
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    } while (bError);

    while (enabled) { //цикл связанный с KeyEvent (пока не true или false - повторять

            System.out.println("Enter key1, key2: ");
            Scanner key1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner key2 = new Scanner(System.in);

            String k1 = prop.getProperty(key1.nextLine());
            String k2 = prop.getProperty(key2.nextLine());

            if (k1 == null) {
                System.out.println("Первый ключ задан неправильный\n");
            }
            if (k2 == null) {
                System.out.println("Второй ключ задан неправильный\n");
            }
            System.out.println("key1: " + k1 + "\nkey2: " + k2);
        }
   // System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Пример кода обработчика клавиши:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Mykey implements KeyListener {
boolean enabled = false;
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
    {
        enabled = true;
        //return;
    }

}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

}
}
```

Comment: Насколько я помню консоль не может отловить esc. Вам необходим другой подход c подвязкой gui

Comment: Пользователю при работе через консоль необходимо будет ввести esc, а Вам отловить и сделать выход.

Comment: То есть, есть возможность только через цикл и использование "Scanner"... Я просто думал вдруг есть без ввода трех символов и считывание, а нажал клавишу и она сама считалась...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как правильно заметил JVic, консольная java-программа не сможет среагировать на нажатие клавиши escape. Но смогла бы среагировать программа на C. Мостик к этой возможности можно прокинуть через [JNI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface). **Не думаю, что это подходящее решение данной проблемы**, но всё же приведу его в просветительских целях и баловства ради. Первым делом нам нужен сам java-код. Поместим его в **ExitOnEscape.java**:

```
public class ExitOnEscape implements Runnable {
    private volatile boolean doTheStuff = true; // Флаг активности рабочего потока

    public native boolean readConsole();

    public void run() { // Рабочий поток
        while (doTheStuff) { // Работать пока установлен флаг
            System.out.println("Doing something..."); // Основная логика программы
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException exc) {}
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        new Thread(this).start(); // Запускаем рабочий поток

        while(true) { // В главном потоке читаем консоль нативной функцией в бесконечном цикле
            if(readConsole()) { // Если нажат escape
                doTheStuff = false; // Сбрасываем флаг активности
                break; // И выходим из цикла
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.loadLibrary("ExitOnEscape");
        ExitOnEscape exitOnEscape = new ExitOnEscape();
        exitOnEscape.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Как видно, в коде есть только две строки отличающиеся от того, с чем приходится сталкиваться ежедневно. Это объявление нативного метода

```
public native boolean readConsole();
```

и загрузка библиотеки

```
System.loadLibrary("ExitOnEscape");
```

Компилируем его:

```
javac -h . ExitOnEscape.java
```

Ключ `-h` указывает в какой каталог сгенерировать заголовочный файл для нашей будущей библиотеки. В рабочем каталоге должен появиться файл **ExitOnEscape.h** со следующим содержимым:

```
/* DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - it is machine generated */
#include <jni.h>
/* Header for class ExitOnEscape */

#ifndef _Included_ExitOnEscape
#define _Included_ExitOnEscape
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
/*
 * Class:     ExitOnEscape
 * Method:    readConsole
 * Signature: ()Z
 */
JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ExitOnEscape_readConsole
  (JNIEnv *, jobject);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
#endif
```

В нём интересно только объявление функции, имеющее вид `Java_<имя класса>_<имя метода>`. Первый параметр функции `JNIEnv` - это указатель на таблицу функций механизма JNI, служащих для обеспечения взаимодействия между java- и c-кодом. Второй параметр имеет тип `jobject` и принимает экземпляр класса `ExitOnEscape`. Возвращает функция `jboolean` соответствующий типу `boolean` в java.
`JNIEXPORT` и `JNICALL` - это зависимые от компилятора макро-определения для экспортирования функций, особого внимания они не заслуживают.

А теперь самая интересная часть - реализация этой функции. Опишем её в файле **ExitOnEscape.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include "ExitOnEscape.h"

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ExitOnEscape_readConsole(JNIEnv* env, jobject obj) {
    char c = getch(); // Считываем введённый символ
    if (c == 27) // Если это escape
        return JNI_TRUE; // Возвращаем true
    else
        return JNI_FALSE; // Иначе false
}
```

Для компиляции в Windows я использовал [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/):

```
gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include" ^
-I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32" ^
-shared -o ExitOnEscape.dll ExitOnEscape.c
```

В рабочем каталоге должен появиться файл *ExitOnEscape.dll*. После этого можно запускать java-программу командой `java ExitOnEscape`

Comment: я мимокрокодил, но это жесть, как стрелять в муху из BFG :)

Comment: Решение очень интересное) Увы использовать связку двух языков в моем случае не вариант - изучаю java и реализация только на ней

Comment: следовательно... Да и скажу по правде - это для меня слегка трудноовато и я бы додумался до такого только очень хорошо и долго посидев над мат. частью - преподаватель сразу раскусит. Я взял куда более простое решение с проверкой введенного словосочетание, хотя и думал, что "KeyEvent" - такая панацея и работает везде)

Comment: @goldstar_labs я пришёл в java-разработку через JNI и на меня часто нападает ностальгия :)

Comment: @Виктор теперь вы знаете о такой особенности Java и можете невзначай упомянуть о ней перед преподавателем. Возможно, он оценит :) А может и просто когда-нибудь пригодится.