# Необходимо написать JNI для возможности отмены запущенных потоков нажатием клавиши Esc

Tags: java, многопоточность, jni

Есть некая программа которая считывает из из файла заданного пользователем пути к папкам и считает количество файлов в папке и всех ее подпапках. Для каждой папки создается отдельный поток, в котором происходят вычисления. Необходимо при нажатии кнопки esc остановить поиск и вывести результаты которые посчитались на данный момент.
На просторах stack overflow нашла решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/819757/384468.
в котором создается нативная библиотека.
И тут я застряла, ее абсолютно не получается загрузить и соединить с логикой программы.
Плюс, возможно кто знает подробную статью как создавать библиотеки для Windows на С?
После этих строчек в глазах почернело
Для компиляции в Windows я использовал MinGW-w64:

1.gcc -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias

2. -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include"
3. -I"%JAVA_HOME%\include\win32"
4. -shared -o ExitOnEscape.dll ExitOnEscape.c

При попытке загрузить библиотеку естественно выдает: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no ExitOnEscape in java.library.path:

Возможно кто-то имеет несколько лишних минут, чтобы взглянуть на код. Спасибо всем большое за ванимание!)

Comment: Заранее скажу, что солидарен с коллегами из того ответа - это как из пушки по воробьям, тем не менее в просветительных целях это не важно.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что эта ошибка у вас возникает в Java коде на строчке `System.loadLibrary("имя dll библиотеки");`?
Если да, то все дело в том, что dll, которую вы должны были собрать компилятором для C (например, вышеописанным gcc, идущем в комплекте ПО MinGW) должна лежать в каталоге, который указан в PATH для вашего запускаемого java-проекта, т.е. в директории, где ищутся остальные исходники.

Comment: Например, в качестве теста можете положить dll в папку `/target` вашего проекта (если вы работаете через IDE по типу IntelliJ IDEA, то она попадает в PATH при запуске, т.к. она при компиляции туда складывает файлы). Подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403788/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-dll-in-java-library-path).
Тем не менее складывается устойчивое впечатление, что вашу задачу следует решать каким-то иным более простым и адекватным способом, например, через [Ctrl+C вместо Esc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611931/catching-ctrlc-in-java).

Comment: А ESC точно надо именно в консоли нажимать? А то может у тебя вообще JavaFX/Swing/AWT/Android

Comment: точно в консоли(

Comment: Ну тогда надо воспользоваться советами выше - положить dll рядом с jar файлом